# On separable Banach spaces having quotients isomorphic to $c_{0}$

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. It is known that if $X$ has a quotient isomorphic to $c_{0}$, then, for every $\epsilon>0$, $X$ has a quotient that is $(1+\epsilon)$-isomorphic to $c_{0}$. This result also holds if $c_{0}$ is replaced by $C[0,1]$. I have several questions about this result.

Question 1: Is there a self-contained proof of this result？

Question 2: Can the separability of $X$ in this result be removed?

Thank you!

Comment: For question 2, the answer is trivially yes: if $X$ has a quotient $Y$ isomorphic to $c_0$, apply the result for the separable space $Y$.

Comment: For (1) you cannot avoid using the non distortability of $\ell_!$ in the case that the quotient is $C[0,1]$. You cannot avoid something close to Pelczynski's argument from there even when $X$ is isomorphic to $C[0,1]$ because $C[0,1]$ is arbitrarily distortable.  The case of $c_0$ is easy from the non distortability of $\ell_!$, as I mentioned to you in an email, and implies the  non distortability of $\ell_!$ for weak$^*$ equivalent norms on $\ell_!$.

Comment: The case that the quotient is $C[0,1]$ is more difficult than the case of $c_{0}$. Now I understand what you said.